# file.write() isn't writing to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I'm trying to send a file over a socket. Everything seems to be working properly except for the file not writing properly. I snipped the code down to the major issue but can send the full server and client code if necessary.

```
if inst == "send":
            try:
                print ("Receiving...")
                l = s.recv(1024)
                with open('torecv.py', 'wb') as f:
                    print ("Writing...")
                    newFile = l.decode("UTF-8")
                    f.write(newFile)
                    f.close()
                print ("Done Receiving")
            except:
                pass
```

The output returns:

```
Receiving...
Writing...
```

and newFile saves the correct data which says to me that it is running f.write is the problem because "torecv.py" is empty.

I'm pretty new to python so go easy on me. Thanks!

Comment: When using "with open" you dont need the close() function

Comment: That is true, but it doesn’t solve my problem, I tried it both ways. @marphlap

Comment: Is it me or it seems strange that OP decoded the binary data and then trying to write it in file..?

Comment: If you print "newFile" does it show anything?

Comment: @Agent_Orange I also tried without decoding as I wasn’t sure which would yield the correct result. Neither yielded any result.

Comment: why decode when you have it in binary mode, either write to plain txt file without the `b` in `wb` and then do `f.write(l)`

Comment: @marphlap printing newFile prints the file (I’ve run it both with and without decoding, it prints fine, but doesn’t write.

Comment: I agree with @FishingCode, try with open('torecv.py', 'w') as f:

Comment: Can you write `print(newFile)` to check if you have data to be written?

Comment: `except: pass` could be hiding a million things. Take out the exception catch and see what materialises.

Comment: I switched wb to w and it worked. Thanks @FishingCode

Comment: @alaniwi Makes a good point, I can't think of many situations where `except: pass` is the right thing to do.